# How can I prevent a recording from being inadvertently stopped?

Tags: ios, recording

After I hit Record on my iPhone for video or audio recordings, the Stop button is too easily triggered accidentally, e.g. by the wind or physical matter (dust, paper) that manages to touch the phone screen. How can I force the phone to require more than a touch (e.g. a password) to stop or pause a recording?

Comment: *Wind, dust, paper?!?*  The iPhone screen is capacitive touch meaning in order for it to register a touch input the medium *must* conduct electricity.  Either you like in a high statically charged environment or something else is causing this issue.  Where is your iPhone when you have this recording going on?

Comment: Also the accepted way is to hit the side/mute/lock button which then requires you to enter a password or faceid. If that is too quick what about turning the phone face down?

Comment: @Allan  I definitely know that no human is triggering it. My iPhone is usually on a flat surface, or in a bag where other objects *like the paper* touch it.

Comment: Are you sure that the stop button is *actually* being tapped? And not something like an audio firing from a different app that stops the recording?

Comment: @kumowoon1025 You may be correct! Let's include the second possibility in my question? In addition, how can I prevent "audio firing from a different app that stops the recording"?

Comment: Putting the phone on silent will prevent this issue in some cases, but getting a incoming call is sure to stop all things audio related, unless the phone has do not disturb or airplane mode on.

Comment: One possible reason for automatic triggering could be lack of storage space, if your iPhone internal memory is near full.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent touch, turn on guided access and set it a password for removing it and block the entire screen using [this](https://www.imore.com/how-disable-access-certain-areas-screen-guided-access-iphone-and-ipad) tutorial.

Disable the internet and set it to airplane mode to prevent incoming calls from stopping the video.

Plug it into power and set the screen timeout time to never, so it prevents it from shutdown and autosleep(which is by default disabled when recording).